# How to transform data into suitable table for calculating single linkage clustering in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I'm trying to transform some data into a data table with binary code (for clustering later on). The data I've got looks like this:

```
  order_number  product_id 
            34       37552 
             5       24852 
            10       24852 
            15       33290 
             7       23586 
            35       22395 
             4       16766 
            33       46393 
             9       12916 
            61       12341
```

What I want to get is the column order_number to look like a row header and then to paste 0 or 1 depending on whether a certain product from product_id is in the order_number cell or not. So order_number should be like a basket. I'd like it to look like something similar to this:

```
                  order_number 
 product_id    34              5     
 37552          1              0     
 24852          0              1      
 24852          0              1
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Any help would be highly appreciated, I'm fairly stuck.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple `table`?

```
> table(df$product_id, df$order_number, dnn=c("Product ID","Order Number"))

##           Order Number
## Product ID 4 5 7 9 10 15 33 34 35 61
##      12341 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1
##      12916 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0
##      16766 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
##      22395 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  0
##      23586 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
##      24852 0 1 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0
##      33290 0 0 0 0  0  1  0  0  0  0
##      37552 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  0  0
##      46393 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: I like the solution but OP (for some reason?!!) wants duplicates in the `Product ID` column.

Comment: You're right! Yes, I don't see reason either, but your answer does what the OP seems to want.

Comment: Anyhow, doesn't matter. This is a good solution and hopefully will help someone else if not the OP, him/herself. +1

Comment: I was wrong to think it's necessary but I found more a more suitable way to cluster the data. Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need duplicates of `product_id` but this will give you exact desired output that you presented in your question; however, it is not clean since the desired output is a bit weird;

```
 df.out <- df.org


 df.out[as.character(df.out$order_number)] <- 0
 df.out <- rbind(df.out ,c("NA", "NA",df.out$product_id))

 for (i in 1:(nrow(df.out)-1)){
   for(j in 3:ncol(df.out)){
     df.out[i,j] <- ifelse(df.out[11,j]==df.out[i,2],1,df.out[i,j])
   }
 }


 df.out <- df.out[-11,-1]

 df.out

#    product_id 34 5 10 15 7 35 4 33 9 61 
# 1       37552  1 0  0  0 0  0 0  0 0  0 
# 2       24852  0 1  1  0 0  0 0  0 0  0 
# 3       24852  0 1  1  0 0  0 0  0 0  0 
# 4       33290  0 0  0  1 0  0 0  0 0  0 
# 5       23586  0 0  0  0 1  0 0  0 0  0 
# 6       22395  0 0  0  0 0  1 0  0 0  0 
# 7       16766  0 0  0  0 0  0 1  0 0  0 
# 8       46393  0 0  0  0 0  0 0  1 0  0 
# 9       12916  0 0  0  0 0  0 0  0 1  0 
# 10      12341  0 0  0  0 0  0 0  0 0  1
```

***Data:***

```
df.org <- structure(list(order_number = c(34L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 7L, 35L, 4L, 
33L, 9L, 61L), product_id = c(37552L, 24852L, 24852L, 33290L, 
23586L, 22395L, 16766L, 46393L, 12916L, 12341L)), .Names = c("order_number",
"product_id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```